# How to migrate deployed laravel project in amazon web server

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I deployed a laravel project to amazon web server. I used my git repository to deploy it. I updated composer in the server via sync.sh file. Now I need to migrate using artisan command.
Here is my sync.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo chmod -R a+w /var/www/****serverName***/public_html/*projectName*
sudo php /usr/bin/composer  --working-dir=/var/www/*serverName*/public_html/*projectName*/ update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the following line to your sync.sh file.
sudo php /var/www/****serverName***/public_html/*projectName*/artisan migrate